# Postgres query joining three tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble getting what I believe is a pretty simple query going. I've managed to write my basic query but when I attempt another join on a third table it returns an empty results.

Here's the code that's working:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM "Locations" AS r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Units" AS f 
    ON r.city = f.city AND 
       r.area = f.region
WHERE
    ST_Contains(
        ST_SetSRID(r.geom, 4326),  
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(  
            -75.9165573, 45.3416112
        ), 4326)
    )
```

And the code that's giving me trouble:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM "Locations" AS r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Units" AS f 
    ON r.city = f.city AND 
       r.area = f.region
LEFT OUTER JOIN "UnitDetails" AS fr
    ON fr."UnitId" = f.id
WHERE
    ST_Contains(
        ST_SetSRID(r.geom, 4326),  
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(  
            -75.9165573, 45.3416112
        ), 4326)
    )
```

The UnitId is a foreign key. I've also attempted USING as opposed to ON but I don't understand how Postgres isn't finding the correct results. The columns are being included but they are all null results.

I'm coming from MySQL so I'm wondering if this is just a syntax thing I'm not getting yet.

**NOTE: If I remove the were statement it works perfectly. As soon as I add it in...it doesn't work anymore.**

Comment: Can you show a sample of the "working" (with WHERE clause) and "non-working" (no WHERE clause) output please? It's not totally clear from your description. Please be detailed and specific about what works and doesn't, and what exactly not working means in this context.

Comment: I can't get you a full dump of the dataset right now but basically:

Without Where: The result is complete, the tables are joined correctly and I'm seeing results for all of the fields.

With Where: The third "UnitDetails" table returns ONLY null results.

Comment: Please *edit the question* to add more info, then comment here when done. That way it's readable.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the query, so it appears that the "locations" that contain the specified point do not have "unitdetails" defined for them. Can you test which "units" relate to the "locations" with the point and then independently test whether "unitdetails" are defined for those "units"?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being related to a weird indexing issue that I can't fully explain. the query was indeed perfect, which was extremely annoying.